# WebSocket Issue on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Using Port 80

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am migrating a node.js app from Heroku to AWS Elastic Beanstalk that uses WebSockets on port 80. The WebSockets are returning a 301 error on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but not on Heroku.

To initialize a WebSocket connection click `Create a new note`.

AWS Beanstalk
http://default-environment.psgekxtsbd.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Heroku 
https://murmuring-shelf-40601.herokuapp.com/

This is how I am setting up the WebSockets on the server.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require("express-ws")(app);
app.post("/service/create-account/", (req, res)=> {/*code in here*/});
app.ws('/:noteId/', function (ws, req) {/*code in here*/});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

I have tried adding different configurations in the `.ebextensions` folder like,

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_websockets.conf" :
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content : |
            upstream nodejs {
                server 127.0.0.1:80;
                keepalive 256;
            }

            server {
                listen 80;

                large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

                location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                    # prevents 502 bad gateway error
                    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                    proxy_buffer_size 64k;

                    proxy_pass http://nodejs;
                    proxy_redirect off;

                    # enables WS support
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
            }
```

And

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websocketupgrade.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
             proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";
```

When I add these configurations the HTML fails to load with the error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Here's that URL http://websocketsissue.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

I setup my elastic beanstalk environment as a Web Server Environment using the predefined configuration for Node.js. I did not add any additional resources.

Is there anyway to get WebSockets to work on port 80 using AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Update

I was able to get the single instance environment to work, but not the load balanced, auto scaling environment.

To get the single instance to work I added the following file to `.ebextensions`

```
container_commands:
  01_nginx_websocket_support:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
          ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

Comment: does it work with other ports? i know 8080 is the default configurations have you tried it though or do you need it to be 80

Comment: I just tried moving the ws services to port 8080 and kept the file server and REST services on port 80. It gives me a 502 error on EB, but it works on my localhost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found part of the answer here, https://scopestar.com/blog/aws/elasticbeanstalk/websockets/2016/10/21/enable-websockets-on-elasticbeanstalk-nginx-proxy.html

I added a file in the `.ebextensions` folder with the following content and that fixed it for single instance environments.

```
container_commands:
  01_nginx_websocket_support:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
          ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

To get the WebSockets to work on the load balanced, auto scaling environment I needed to do the following in addition

- Go to the EC2 Dashboard
- Find the Load Balancer that the Elastic Beanstalk project created
- Right click on the Load Balancer and click Edit listener
- Change the Load Balancer Protocol from HTTP to TCP for port 80 and save changes

Comment: How do you determine which load balancer belongs to the eb project?

Comment: @ToriHuang When you create the environment for the EB to be deployed to it will log the name of the load balancer that was created. You can look at the event logs on the EB page and find the name. It should start with awseb.

Comment: I've tried that exact same file but the eb deployment fails with the following error:
`[emerg] 327#0: unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/01_nginx_setup.conf:4` - can you make any sense of this?