# Websocket works on EC2 url but not on ElasticBeanstalk URL

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

**Background**

I have reverse proxy (**nginx**) pointing to ElasticBeanstalk (**ELB**) that is a singleInstance environment type and creates an EC2 instance (**EC2**). I am using a dockerized nodejs app. **nginx** is the entry point for our infrastructure.

**Desciption**

From browser, I can call directly Websocket URLs of an [EC2](http://ec2-52-59-53-38.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/stomp) and of [ELB](http://stag-amio-ws-server.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/stomp) with the same result:

> Welcome to SockJS!

For **nginx** I use the following config (*nginx conf.d/my.conf*) where I only change URLs of **EC2** or **ELB** on the line beginning with `proxy_pass`:

```
location /stomp {
      proxy_pass <{EC2_URL}/stomp OR {ELB_URL}/stomp>;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Websockets on the **EC2** URL are just working fine.

Websockets on the **ELB** URL return an error status back to my client:

> code: 1002, 
>   reason: "Cannot connect to server"

The strangest thing is that my **nginx** server doesn't even log the requests in case of **ELB**.

**Question**

Why is the **ELB** not working in the **nginx** configuration? How to correct it?

**What I tried?**

I have checked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793853/websocket-issue-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-port-80) and a [blog](https://scopestar.com/blog/aws/elasticbeanstalk/websockets/2016/10/21/enable-websockets-on-elasticbeanstalk-nginx-proxy.html) where they advice to override nginx config files like `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` located in `located in /tmp/deployment/config/etc#nginx#nginx.conf`. But my server doesn't have any nginx configuration files on the filesystem...

Comment: So where is nginx running in your case?

Comment: Which port are you connecting through? The default Load Balancer setup may only take traffic from Port 80, or Port 443. If you're using SSL, do you have a certificate set up with ElasticBeanstalk? If you're never getting the request on the Nginx side, then you may never be forwarding from your Load Balancer. To see your load balancer, you should go to EC2 -> Load Balancers on the AWS panel.

Comment: @jonzlin95 We are connecting through port 80. There are no load balancers listed in `EC2 → Load Balancers` but that's not a surprise. Because we only use the ELB with SingleInstance environment type.

Comment: @TarunLalwani `nginx` is the entry point of our infrastructure. It redirects the traffic to ELB (or directly to EC2).

Comment: Remove this `proxy_set_header Host $host;` and try again and see if it works

Comment: @TarunLalwani I will try on Thursday and let you know. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @TarunLalwani man, you're a genius. It worked. Can you please explain why? If you answer I will, of course, accept your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to your `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. The issues is because of the way different server reacts to the Host name header.

Consider when you open the below urls in browser

http://ec2-52-59-53-38.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/stomp
http://stag-ws-server.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/stomp

One being EC2 and one being an ELB. When you send the request to ec2 the Host name is sent as `ec2-52-59-53-38.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`. Now if you have service which listen on port 80 directly or through docker. It is listening to port 80 and doesn't care how the traffic comes to it.

It just knows that if someone reaches the server by any means we respond. Now if you had a nginx on that EC2, that only listens to a specific Virtual Host and doesn't respond to any other host name, then if you send it `ec2-52-59-53-38.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` and it expects to see `abc.mydomain.com` then nginx wont respond to the request.

Same is the case that is happening with your ELB server. You are hosting nginx at some domain name `abc.domain.com` and using `proxy_pass` to pass the traffic to ELB. But using `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, set the host name to `abc.domain.com` and ELB is not able to understand where that host is. So it wont server the request and hence the error